# Unable to access to Auth user info on Laravel

Tags: laravel

Im using Laravel 5.4 i have created the auth system guard using the laravel stuff, i have also created a role based registration form.

At this point all works so far, but for example i want to only certains pages to be available only for admin, so i have created a New User page to allow the admin create users.

My RegisteruserControoller:

```
 namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Proveedor;
use App\RubroProveedor;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests\StoreProveedor;
use App\Http\Requests\UpdateProveedor;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;

use Alert;
use Exception;
use Auth;

class RegisteruserController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct() {

    $this->middleware('role:admin'); 

}


public function index(Request $request)
{

    return view('usuarios.registeruser');
}
```

My problem here is if i use the middleware in construct im always being asked to login again and again, and i need to disable that but keep the guard to allow only admin user create new users.

Im not sure if im clear, im sorry my bad english.

I have created a Middleware called CheckRole:

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class CheckRole
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $role)
    {


        if (! $request->user()->hasRole($role)) {
            abort(401, 'This action is unauthorized.');
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: auth()->user()->hasRole($role), make sure you had implemented hasRole in user model

Comment: yes, already have that hasRole on my model, but when adding 
public function __construct() {

        $this->middleware('role:admin'); 

    }
it always redirects me to login form, and i need to pass that if the user is already logged in...

Comment: I think your $request don't have user() , change to `auth()->user()` instead

Comment: already fixed by creating the make auth model again...not sure whats was wrong...